Solve recurrence relation $2a_n=a_{n-1}+2^n$ using generating functions
Solve $2a_n=a_{n-1}+2^n$, $a_0=1$, for all $n \geq 1$
Here is my attempt:
Let $G(x) = \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, then we have
$$2 \underbrace{\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n}_{G(x)-a_0 x^0} = \underbrace{\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1} x^n}_{x(a_0+a_1x+\cdots)=xG(x)} + \underbrace{\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty 2^n x^n}_{\frac{1}{1-2x}}$$
which leads to
$$2 (G(x)-\underbrace{a_0x^0}_{=1}) = xG(x) + \frac{1}{1-2x}$$
simplifying
$$2G(x)-xG(x)=\frac{1}{1-2x} + 2 \iff G(x)(2-x)=\frac{3-4x}{1-2x}$$
and we get
$$G(x)=\frac{3-4x}{(1-2x)(2-x)}$$
now, with partial fractions I get
$$G(x) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{1-2x} + \frac{5}{3}\frac{1}{2-x}$$
So the first summand should be $\frac{2}{3}2^n=\frac{1}{3} 2^{n+1}$ but I can't figure what is the 2nd summand, that is, $\frac{1}{2-x}$. I solved this using homogenous and particular solutions and I get $a_n = \frac{1}{3} 2^{n+1} + \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{2^n}$, which I checked for $n=1$ and it looked good, also the first summand is the same as here. How to finish this, can you see the mistake? Thanks

$\frac{1}{2-x} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1 - x/2}$, which you can again expand as a geometric series.

Shouldn'it be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n x^n$ instead of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n x^n$?

ah yes, I originally did like that, then we have $\frac{2x}{1-2x}$ but if I remember correctly, at the end there is still this $\frac{1}{2-x}$ thing. I’ll edit the question with the fix tomorrow. thanks

@ViktorVaughn ah yes that’s it. I considered that manipulation but I just thought “this is still nothing”. thanks

After the correction mentionned in comment,
$$2G(x)-xG(x)=\frac{2x}{1-2x} + 2 \iff G(x)(2-x)=\frac{2-2x}{1-2x}$$
$$ \iff G(x)=\frac{1-x}{(1-x/2)(1-2x)}$$
$$ \iff G(x)=\frac{2/3}{1-2x}+\frac{1/3}{1-x/2}
$$
hence
$$a_n=\frac{2^{n+1}}3+\frac1{3\cdot2^n}.$$
A more elementary method is to find first a particular solution of the recurrence of the form $x_n=\alpha2^n$ ($2\alpha2^n=\alpha2^{n-1}+2^n\iff\alpha=\frac23$), and notice that $(a_n-x_n)$ is then a geometric sequence with ratio $\frac12$, i.e. $a_n=\frac232^n+\frac c{2^n}$, with $c=a_0-\frac23=\frac13$.

Using your definition of $G(x)$, we have
$$\begin{align}
G(x)
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \\
&= a_0 x^0 + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2a_n x^n \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n-1} + 2^n) x^n \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1} x^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n x^n \right) \\
&= 1 + \frac{x}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2x)^n \\
&= 1 + \frac{x}{2} G(x) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{2x}{1 - 2x}.
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$G(x) = \frac{1 + \frac{x}{1-2x}}{1 - \frac{x}{2}} = \frac{1-x}{1-2x} \cdot \frac{2}{2-x} = \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{1}{1-x/2} + \frac{2}{1-2x}\right),$$
where we have used partial fraction decomposition in the last step.  Hence
$$G(x) = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (x/2)^n + 2(2x)^n,$$
from which it follows that
$$a_n = \frac{2^{-n} + 2^{n+1}}{3}.$$

In the very first line, it should be
$$2 \underbrace{\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n}_{G(x)-a_0 x^0} = \underbrace{\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1} x^n}_{x(a_0+a_1x+\cdots)=xG(x)} + \underbrace{\sum_\limits{n=\color{red}{1}}^\infty 2^n x^n}_{\frac{\color{red}{2x}}{1-2x}}$$
And then everything works. Also, to simplify $1/(2-x)$, just do
$$\frac{1}{2-x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-x/2}=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2^n}$$
Hope this helps. :)

Why not telescopic summation
$2a_{n}-a_{n-1}=2^n$ gives
$$2a_1-a_0=2$$
$$2^2a_2-2a_1=2\cdot 2^2$$
$$2^3a_3-2^2a_2=2^2\cdot 2^3$$
$$...........................$$
$$...........................$$
$$2^{n-1}a_{n-1}-2^{n-2}a_{n-2}=2^{n-2}\cdot 2^{n-1}$$
$$2^na_n-2^{n-1}a_{n-1}=2^{n-1}\cdot 2^n$$
Adding all these we get
$$2^na_n-a_0=\sum_{1}^{n} 2^{2k-1}=2\frac{4^n-1}{4-1}$$
Giving us $$a_n=\frac{2^{n+1}+2^{-n}}{3}.$$
